# How can I make the string in function work?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make it work.....I'm assuming the array I'm getting not always have the type and value those 2 keys. I'm trying to make the function to work for multiple different arrays. Here is the code I have so far...

```
let inventory = [{
     type: "machine",
     value: 5300
 }, {
     type: "machine",
     value: 650
 }, {
     type: "duck",
     value: 20
 }, {
     type: "furniture",
     value: 1000
 }, {
     type: "duck",
     value: 25
 }, {
     type: "machine",
     value: 77
 }]

 function sum(x, y, z) {
     // store the total for each type
     let result = {};
     for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         let item = x[i];
         let item_type = item['y'];
         if (result[item_type]) {
             result[item_type] += item['z'];
         }
         else {
             result[item_type] = item['z'];
         }
     }
     return result;
 }
 console.log(sum(inventory, 'type', 'value'))
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem then ?

Comment: Object.hasOwnProperty

Comment: Write the question clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
item[y]
```

instead of `item['y']`. The same for `item['z']`, it becomes `item[z]`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove single quote "'" from 'y' and 'z'.
 **Inside the loop you need to replace**

let item_type = item['y']; by let item_type = item[y]; an so on

```
let inventory = [
  {type:   "machine", value: 5300},
  {type:   "machine", value:  650},
  {type:      "duck", value:   20},
  {type: "furniture", value: 1000},
  {type:      "duck", value:   25},
  {type:   "machine", value:   77}
]

function sum(x,y,z){
    console.log(x[1][y]);
    console.log(y);
    console.log(z);
// store the total for each type
   let result = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   let item = x[i];
   console.log(item);
   let item_type = item[y];
   if (result[item_type]) {
      result[item_type]+= item[y];
   }
   else  {
      result[item_type] = item[z];
   }
}
return result;
}

console.log(sum(inventory, 'type', 'value'))
```